# Google Sheets AppsScript for inserting new rows based on dropdown values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some dropdown menus in my sheet.
When a selection is made in one of them, I want a number of new rows to be inserted in the sheet.
Specifically, I want to be able to add the row(s) either above or below a specific existing row that I specify by the text present in column C.
I then want the inserted row to populate text of my choosing in column C.
Lastly, I want any inserted row(s) to continue the formula pattern I have in columns B and D.

Example spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tIYnuJU1t3tl0kk4nTqNB7zj4ndXM6R2PpujDao8Uwc/edit#gid=0

For Example: If the "tiger" option in Menu 1 is selected, insert three rows after the "First step" Process Step Description, and name their Process Step Descriptions "has stripes", "is orange and black". and "has sharp teeth".

I still have so much trouble writing these scripts... I know how to insert a row now and do simple things like "getActiveSpreadsheet" but I get confused by much more. I get started and end up with something convoluted that doesn't work.

Below is my best attempt. I know it doesn't make much sense as it is a mish-mash of a few different scripts I've had help completing for other tasks. I've put some placeholders in square brackets for the reference I want to make but don't know how.

```
function DynamicFlowchart(range, sourceRange){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
range.setValue(rule);

function onEdit (){
var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());


 if(aCell=="tiger"){
  ss.insertRowAfter([the process step description that says "first step"]);
  ss.getRange(ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(), 3).setValue("has stripes");
  ss.insertRowAfter([the process step description that says "has stripes"]);
  ss.getRange(ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(), 3).setValue("is orange and black");
  ss.insertRowAfter([the process step description that says "is orange and black"]);
  ss.getRange(ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(), 3).setValue("has sharp teeth");
}
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `If the "tiger" option in Menu 1 is selected, insert three rows after the "First step" Process Step Description, and name their Process Step Descriptions "has stripes", "is orange and black". and "has sharp teeth".` Would you please explain: how does one know 1) "three" rows are to be inserted, 2) to inserted the rows **after** row#2 (you said `add the row(s) either above **OR** below a specific existing row`), 3) the descriptions are "has stripes", "is orange and black" and "has sharp teeth"? I sympathise with the learning curve for scripting but would please include your best script.

Comment: Please see my best script I've added to my post above!

Comment: Your "best" script was worth posting. I hope that you can compare it to the answer and see some of the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to respond to dropdown "(Menu1)" by:

- inserting three rows below
- adding certain process steps, and
- removing the relevant Data Validation in the new rows (added by Tedinoz)

The following differences between the OP's script and this answer are worth noting:

- `onEdit(e)` - the answer makes use of the [onEdit Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). This simplifies much of the scripting.

  - I have left a number of `Logger.log` statements in the code that the OP can use to identify the status of variables
  - Also note: `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` which will list **ALL** of the event objects for a given edit.
- `if(aCell=="tiger"){` Vs `if (editedSheetName != "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger"){`

  - `if(aCell=="tiger"){` = *good*
  - `if (editedSheetName !== "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger"){` = *better*
  - as the OP's spreadsheet becomes more complex, it will become important to make sure that the edit is on a given sheet, and in a given column.
- `!==` AND `||`

  - combination of `!==` and `||` will identify an "invalid" edit and enable the user to stop the script
- `editedCell.offset(1, 1, 3).setValues(steps)`

  - a single line to the project descriptions
  - update of the three cells is done by using an array `steps` to update a range defined by using `offset`

---

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedCell = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol)
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", the edited cell Range = "+editedCell.getA1Notation())

  // test for edit on sheet:"Input", in Column:A and value:"tiger"
  if (editedSheetName !== "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger") {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: INVALID edit: sheet <> input &/or col <> 1 &/or value <>tiger")
    return
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(editedRow, 3);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to thge right)
    var steps = [["has stripes"], ["is orange and black"], ["has sharp teeth"]]
    editedCell.offset(1, 1, 3).setValues(steps)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    editedSheet.getRange(3, 1, 3).setDataValidation(null)
  }
}
```

---

**AFTER**

[image: after]

Comment: Thank you so much! And much appreciate your detailed learning notes. A couple followup questions I'm looking to solve... 1) How do I continue the numbering in columns B and D as new rows are added? 2) How can I specify that I want to insert the rows after a specific Process Step Description? I looked around and my best guess is to use something like the following: `var getrowindex = getRange(1, 1, getLastRow(), 1).getValues();  
for(var i = 0; i < getrowindex.length; i++){ if(getrowindex[i] == "First step"){ Logger.log(getrowindex[i]) } }`

Comment: `How can I specify that I want to insert the rows after a specific Process Step Description?`  _This_ question dealt with a specific operation and you didn't provide any context for the spreadsheet scenario and relevance of the operation. The question is silent on details relating to "the rows after a specific Process Step Description", how the dropdowns for menu 1, 2 and 3 are inserted in specific rows, and other aspects. This is too much to be addressed here; please post a new question and provide a comprehensive explanation of your scenario and the outcome that you want.

Comment: `How do I continue the numbering in columns B and D as new rows are added?` The question is silent on the logic behind the numbering in Columns B and D _before_ &/or _after_ inserting new rows. More information is required (too much to do here) and I suggest that you post a new question and include a detailed explanation of the purpose/logic of the numbering in columns B and D.

Comment: Thank you for your direction! I will do that.